# Finding the intersection of 3 sets when given all information (except the intersection)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

---

Info:

104 students were asked if they like math, science or humanities.

35 don't like either

21 students like math *only*

17 students like science *only*

4 students like humanities *only*

15 students like math and humanities

13 students like math and science

17 students like humanities and science

---

Question:

how many students like all three subjects?

---

Work:

I'm not even sure what the formula is for finding n(A∩B∩C) is. But when I used the following formula, this is what I got:

formula: n(A∩B∩C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A∪B∪C)

established facts:

where n(A) = 49 (21 + 13 + 15)

where n(B) = 47 (13 + 17 + 17)

where n(C) = 36 (15 + 17 + 4)

where n(A∪B∪C) = 69 (104 [total] - 35 [neither])

substitution:

n(A∩B∩C) = 49 + 47 + 36 - 69
n(A∩B∩C) = 132 - 69
n(A∩B∩C) = 63?!

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?? Or if there is a formula that is applicable to this particular situation (missing intersection) could someone please let me know of that??
Because the intersection cannot be 63...

Comment: Did the students have to choose one? I don't understand the first comment that $35$ don't like either. Do you mean any of the three?

Comment: You should say that $35$ of the students don't like any of the subjects.

Comment: @DerekLuna yes the 35 students don't like any of the three courses

Answer (score 1):

In general using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C|-|B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C| \implies$

$|A \cap B \cap C| = |A \cup B \cup C|  -(|A| + |B| + |C|) + |A \cap B| + |A \cap C|+|B \cap C|$.

In this case, your conditions are a bit different as we have the strict conditions of "only" for $A,B,C$ so the subtraction becomes easier for those terms. Then using a Venn Diagram one can see that $A \cap B,A \cap C,B \cap C \subseteq A \cap B \cap C$, and are oversubstracted. Hence now we know how to substract so that we have the following:

$-2|A \cap B \cap C| = (104-35)-(21+17+4)-(15+13+17)=-18 \implies$

$|A \cap B \cap C| = 9$.

What was done was this: Cancel out easily the elements (students) strictly in singleton sets, then substract the $2$-intersections so that we are left with $69 - (STUFF)= |A \cup B \cup C| - (STUFF) = -3|A \cap B \cap C|.$

Comment: The $-15$ should be a $-18$ and the $-3$ coefficient should be a $-2$. I think the difference comes from the fact that you don't start with the entire circle $A$ but I'd have to look a bit more.

Comment: Thank you, bad calculations on my part.

Comment: @DerekLuna, thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

$104-35=69$ students like at least one subject.

Then, $69-(21+17+4)=27$ students like at least two subjects.

But all of the students that like all three (call this $n$) also like at least two, so we have counted those students three times by adding $15+13+17 = 45$ (once for each of the three groups). We only want to count them once, so we subtract out $2n$:

$45 - 2n = 27 \implies n = 9.$

Comment: I may have done something wrong, perhaps you can take a look?

Comment: @John, thank for the input, it makes more sense now :))